# Map undefined when working with reddit json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react and routers to display the threads from a series of subreddits when the user clicks on a specific option. However I keep getting the error of "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" and I cannot figure out why.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { fetchCatThreads } from './RedditApi';
import ThreadCard from './ThreadCard';
import Loading from './Loading';

export default class CatsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      threads: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    let threads = await fetchCatThreads();
    this.setState({ threads:threads.thread, loading: false });
  }
   render() {
    return (
      <div className="threads">
        {this.state.loading ? <Loading /> : this.state.threads.map((thread) => {
            return <ThreadCard thread={thread} />
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that means `this.state.threads` is `undefined`, not `map` - which suggests that whatever `fetchCatThreads` returns does not have a `thread` property - so the problem is in your `fetchCatThreads` function

Comment: Can you please post your `fetchCatThreads` function definition code?

Comment: Here's fetchCatThreads looks like: `const API_URL = 'https://www.reddit.com';
export async function fetchCatThreads() {
  let response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/r/cats.json`);
  return response.json();
}`

Comment: the resultant object from that call has two root properties, `kind` and `data` - so of course `.thread` is undefined - in fact, the word `thread` does not exist at all in the response - so it's not even a possibility that you need to access something deeper in the result object

Comment: try `this.setState({ threads:threads.data.children, loading: false });` instead

Answer (score 0):

As @Bravo stated in the comments, your passing back `undefined` (as `.thread` does not exist). pass back `threads.data.children || []` which will default to an array to prevent errors in the case of unexpected results:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    let threads = await fetchCatThreads();
    this.setState({ threads: threads.data.children || [], loading: false });
  }
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: yes, well, that does make more sense, since that's the data that is returned :p